# Want to hide error from console $(...).focusOut is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am really surprised why i am getting this error on console because this code is working absolutely fine. Actually on hover i am showing div over image. Div smoothly slideUp on hover for that i am using this code

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slide').focusOut(
              function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(600);

          });
        $('.slide').hover(function(){      
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(600);
          });
        });

  </script>
```

But if i remove focusout then it stucks while sliding up. Hope i am able to understand you. what i want is how can i stop this error or what is the alternative of this

I have edited my code and now it is working absolutely fine

```
 $(function(){
        $('.slide').on('hover',function(){      
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(600);
          });

        $('.slide').on('mouseleave',function(){

            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(600);

          });

 });
```

Comment: Should be `focusout` not `focusOut`

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error vansihed, then it worked. What is not working is your logic in code maybe. But that was not your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `on` function:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slide').on('focusout',function(){
           //CODE
        });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: It comes and then hide not stay until mouse is hover

Comment: i think you are looking for the mouseleave event

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: can you go to this [link](http://www.dev.ludhianalive.com/) on bottom you can see carousel hover on image

Comment: okay error is vanished now thanks for your code it helps  me alot

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Try it...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slide').focusout(
           //CODE
          });
              });

  </script>
```